# Best full text search alternative to MS SQL, C++ solution

Tags: c++, sql-server, full-text-search, lucene, lucene.net

What is the best full text search alternative to Microsoft SQL?  (which works with MS SQL)

I'm looking for something similar to [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) and [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) but without the .NET and Java requirements. I would also like to find a solution that is usable in commercial applications.

Comment: One note of caution on [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/): it tends to lag behind Apache's [Java Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) (the "official" Lucene). Lucene.NET is a port of Java Lucene, and the community around Java Lucene is larger. For obvious reasons, this can sometimes be a problem.

Comment: I prefer [Xapian](http://xapian.org/) - pure C++ Search Engine Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [CLucene](http://clucene.wiki.sourceforge.net/) - It's a well maintained C++ port of java Lucene. It's currently licenced under LGPL and we use it in our commercial application.

Performance is incredible, however you do have to get your head around some of the strange API conventions.

Answer (score 3):

[Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com) is one of the best solutions. It's written in C++ and has amazing performance.

Comment: Lucene is not for MSSQL either, you can 2 choices: index documents prior passing it to DB or let indexing engine go through DB itself. Sphinx can't crawl MSSQL automatically as far as I know, but it has best indexing performance.

Answer (score 1):

[DT Search](http://www.dtsearch.com/) is hands down the best search tool I have used.  They have a number of solutions available.  Their Engine will run on Native Win32, Linux or .NET.  It will index pretty much every kind of document you might have (Excel, PDF, Word, etc.)  I did some benchmarks comparisons a while ago and it was the easiest to use and had the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is based on Lucene, but accessible via HTTP, so it can be used from any platform.

Answer (score 0):

I second Sphinx, but [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is also not so bad despite the Java. :) If you are not dealing with too much data spread out etc., then also look into MySQL's [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). We are using it to search across a 20 GB database.